# How to integrate Java with Tally application

Tags: java, tally

I need to integrate my java web application with Tally software.

Is it possible? Please provide some idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tally ERP 9 implements SOAP web services. More [here](http://tallysolutions.com/newwebsite/html/index.html). Accessing an application using SOAP is common technique in Java and is supported by many libraries.

Comment: The link says Page not found! Sorry, but the page you were looking for could not be found. Could you please provide a working link?

Answer (score 6):

Well, Tally doesn't support SOAP, but does support a basic **XML/HTTP** interface, as one of the integration options. Some of my experiments with Tally is captured here: http://subbaraman.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/playing-with-tally-software/. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Additionally, I would refer to this: https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/integration_capabilities/introduction.htm ... looks like Tally has improved their documentation with regard to Integration capabilities.