# How to use tally api in android

Tags: android, ksoap2, saxparser

I am trying to integrate tally api's in my app how am i going to use that I
used sax parser and soap parser both but no use for me may be 
i am not getting proper way that how am i going to use that if some one is having idea about that then please help me .

I am using xml parsing for that but not getting any result or solution

http://www.pcsalt.com/android/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-android/#sthash.2dyKVb8B.dpbs

Please help me

Comment: Hope it helps-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536179/how-to-integrate-java-with-tally-application

Comment: yes i am having that solution thanks

Comment: happy coding. All the best